# Output Variable from Javascript to PHP/HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am very new to javascript/jquery. I am trying to get a variable from a url, for example.

`www.site.com?user=admin`

I was able to find this for getting the variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}
$.urlParam('user');
</script>
```

but now I need to know how to `echo` it to the screen, preferably in PHP but HTML would also work.

I'm sure this is a basic question, but I can't find anything on it. Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: Why do you need javascript to get it? You can get that directly with PHP using [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Comment: You want to 'echo' it to the screen with PHP... Or HTML. Okay, so what is it you're trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: I know I can use GET with PHP. but I am doing a jquery refresh on a mysql query that is based on that variable. For some reason, when I do the refresh, it stops grabbing the variable from the URL, even with GET in the PHP code and even with the variable staying the same. So My thought is I need to grab it with this and see if that helps. Maybe I am mistaken?

Comment: whats a jQuery refresh?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#records').load('user_records.php?user='+username).fadeIn("slow");
}, 30000); // refresh every 30 seconds
</script>
`

Comment: I think you're going wrong about your debugging approach. Once JavaScript is running, it's impossible for PHP to update information on client side unless explicitly requested via AJAX. First of all, tell us whether there even is a request going out (*Chrome Developer Tools - Network*). Next you should check where `username` is defined, whether it is in scope... In this case, it has to be in global scope. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just append the value of the variable inside the html container like.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}

$(function(){
   $("#userName").text($.urlParam('user'));
});

</script>
```

**in html**

```
<span id="userName"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['user']))
{
     echo $_REQUEST['user']; 
}
?>
```

Use this code where you want to display user name.

-

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

echo "<script type='text/javascript'> 
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}
$.urlParam('user');
</script>";


 ?>
```

Comment: one what's the point of echo'ing a plain javascript code in php. second does this answer OP's question?

Comment: we can echo javascript in php  see view source in this it is appliedhttp://pamaquantresearch.com/strategyList.html